# vsftpd returns wrong pasv_address

Tags: networking, dns, ftp, ip, vsftpd

I use vsftpd on my CentOS6.4 home server. Recently I noticed that I can connect to the ftp but LIST command fails because vsftpd is returning wrong IP address when entering passive mode.

I figured out that I need to change vsftpd.conf from

```
pasv_address=my.domain.com
```

to

```
pasv_address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (server's IP address)
```

to make it work.

Since my server's IP address is not static, I use a dynamic DNS service and the service is working fine. However, it seems vsftpd returns an old IP address as pasv_address.

Can anyone suggest why this happens and how to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try putting the following line in your `vsftpd.conf`

```
pasv_addr_resolve=YES
```

Then you should be able to put a hostname instead of an IP address as the `pasv_address` ; `pasv_addr_resolv` defaults to `NO`

Comment: Worked perfectly. This should be the accepted answer.